# html table colspan not working as expected

Tags: html, html-table

HTML concepts are so terrible sometimes.

This is my code using colspan in html table, and doesn't look as I expect.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is: **cell 'a'** should look **3 cell wide**, **cell 'b'** should look **2 cell wide**, **cell 'c'** should look **1 cell wide**.

What it is doing is: **cell 'a'** is **2 cells wide**, cell **'b' & 'c'** is **1 cell wide.**

Any Suggestions thanks.

Comment: It's good just you can't see 3 cell cause you have max 2 cell...https://jsfiddle.net/za3uybnr/2/

Comment: is all a,b,c in the same row?

Comment: No @affaz,
a is in first row, b & c are in second row.

Comment: column spaning works as intended. You might be looking for a styling solution. Answer below. @SushilKumarJain

Answer (score 6):

Attribute `colspan` determines how many columns a cell overlaps with respect to other cells, not the absolute size of those columns. In your case, **span 2 has two spans**. how you can say it is not? don't judge it by width of a cell. span is not the width. You have to add another smaller columns to **appear** it as a column of two spans.

**See the solution for your expectation in code snippet last example.**

```html
<h3>Example 1</h3>

<table border="1">
    <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td><td>col3</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3">a</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">b</td><td colspan="1">c</td></tr>
</table>

<h3>Example 2</h3>

<table border="1">
    <tr><td width="80px">wide col1</td><td>col2</td><td>col3</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3">span 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">span 2</td><td colspan="1">span 1</td></tr>
</table>

<h3>Your case</h3>

<table border="1">
    <tr><td colspan="3">span 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" width="66%">span 2</td><td width="33%">span 1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for answering, I see your answer and examples, but first thing, I cannot use example 1 & 2 and


I did not mention in question, I am creating these tables dynamically though, and there are many cells with b & c, so calculating width can be difficult.
BUT I don't think there is any other solution.


should I go on and calculate width for every cell according to its colspan ? what do u suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You have already answered your question as your code is working fine but your max count is only 2. If you add another row you can see the desired results.

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
]
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">column 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">column 2</td>
    <td>column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column n</td>
    <td>column n</td>
    <td>column n</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
table {
 width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>column</td>
    <td>column</td>
    <td>column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">column 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">column 2</td>
    <td>column 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Your code will show the desired result just as you will add another row!!!

Answer (score 0):

So `colspan`s do exactly what they're intended for. There are `n` columns in the table and each table cell `<td>` is one column wide. Using `colspan` spans the cell over more columns. This has nothing to do to each column's `width`.

If you wish for all columns to be of the same `width`, you have to use some styling.

Even though it might be easier to use some CSS grid, a solution for table is as follows:

```css
/* You can make a separate file where you calculate n dynamically and you just
 * link the file with :root { ... } into html <head> */
:root {
  --n: 3; /*number of columns */
}
div {
  /* container for mobile because max-width only works on block elements */
  width: 30em;
  max-width: 100%;
}
table {
  /* table takes the whole container */
  width: 100%;
}
/* the following is enough for this example */
/* td:not([colspan]) {
  width: calc(100% / var(--n));
} */

/* if you don't have any (or well enough placed) table cells without colspan
 * attribute, then you have to calculate each possibilty like so: */
td {
  width: calc(100% / var(--n));
}
td[colspan="2"] {
  width: calc(100% * 2 / var(--n));
}
td[colspan="3"] {
  width: calc(100% * 3 / var(--n));
}
/* and so forth up to maximum possible n */
```

```html
<div>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2>b</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=3>c</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```